# handling accessory state in iOS with EAAccessory

Tags: ios, event-handling, nsinputstream

I am working on an EAAccessory project, and generally have everything working. The accessory is a remote with 5 buttons that interfaces with the dock, and the dock sends commands to my app. This works fine. However, I've been asked to keep track of button state, so I should be able to recognize if buttons 1 and 2 are held together for one second. This seems to be pretty complicated, and I wish this was handled on the dock instead.

What are good programming practices when modeling external accessory state via single commands that are a byte?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about MCU programming in Dock or iOS app? For MCU you have to implement a tick timer interrupt handler and have 5 counters for each button.

Commands sent from Dock to iOS can be individual event commands:
[button 0 is pressed][button 1 is pressed]...[button 0 is released]............[button 1 is released]

Or aggregated: (bit=1 means pressed, 0 means released)
[button state 0x01][button state 0x03]...[button state 0x02]............[button state 0x00]

Comment: Sounds like I need to look into this tick timer interrupt handler. Things are working now, but I'd like to understand how to build this more effectively in the future.